# Unmarshalling struct with arbitrarily repeated nested element

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to parse epub [toc.ncx files](http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx-2005-1.dtd) (make sure to view source). The `navMap` element can contain `navPoint`, and `navPoint` can be arbitrarily nested within itself.

How can I unmarshal nested elements like this in Go?

https://go.dev/play/p/usT17Fls8rg

Self-references just result in stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just needed to reference it like this:

```
type NavPoint struct {
    NavLabel  string     `xml:"navLabel>text"`
    Content  string `xml:"src,attr"`
    NavPoints []NavPoint `xml:"navPoint"`
}
```